# fn:matches executed in oracle SQL return different result as executed in any other XPath 2.0 engine

Tags: regex, oracle, xpath

The XPath statement `fn:matches("Test 123", "^\D*$", "i")` returns `false` in every XPath 2.0 engine (Oxygen, any online tool etc). But when I execute sql statement `select xmlquery('fn:matches("Test 123", "^\D*$", "i")' returning content) from dual;` oracle return `true`.
I am migrating code from using `ora:matches` to `fn:matches`. This regex was correctly interpreted by ora:matches. So the question is not about the regex itself, but about the difference in the outcome.

Can anyone please explain the differences. Is there a way to let oracle act accordingly?
I am using oracle 19c.

I was not able to find any oracle related documentation, which states, that the regex isn't correct.

```sql
select xmlquery('ora:matches("Test 123", "^\D*$", "i")' returning content) from dual; --returns false
select xmlquery('fn:matches("Test 123", "^\D*$", "i")' returning content) from dual; --returns true
select xmlquery('matches("Test 123", "^\D*$", "i")' returning content) from dual; --returns true
```

Comment: It looks like a bug. Log into MyOracle support and report it to Oracle.